# Does the mathematician use the prefix “non” always strictly mean “not necessarily”?

Tags: terminology

I came across https://books.google.com/books/about/Mathematical_Writing.html?id=wpQvBQAAQBAJ
Where it talks abt the difference of non and not

Sounds like mathematician use non to mean “not necessarily” or “not definitely”

Where as “not” means “definitely not”

Does this mean mathematician **always** mean “non” as “not necessarily”?

### Update

Sorry, I just realize the link above doesn't take you to the exact page.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is hard to say with any certainty.  But sometimes this is the convention.

Comment: I would say that "a non-zero real number $x$" means "$x\ne0$". Also "non-decreasing" is commonly used for "weakly increasing", so I guess that's more of an indication than it is a rule.

Comment: Is the set of cases where "non-whatever" means "not necessariily whatever" even non-empty?

Comment: I think that this is more a question of English grammar than mathematics.

Comment: How would a mathematician use it then?

Comment: Can you provide an actual example of your problem? "non" is not an English word, but rather a prefix used to form some English words but not according to any general rule: "non-decreasing" is a good word but "non-significant' just isn't a word (the right word is "insignificant").

Comment: "non-negative" and "non-zero" seem to mean definitely not.  So I'd say, no, mathematicians *don't* always do this.

Comment: The more I think about it I'd say mathematicians *never* say "non" to mean "not nescessarily".  At least, I can' think of any case where they do and every case I can think of they don't.  Trouble is there doesn't seem to be any word for "not necessarily".

Comment: Can you link to the passage in the book where they discuss this?

Comment: reproduce the text in book as image when i realize the link doesn't really work

Comment: Thanks for including the extract. I think the author of the book was having an over-pedantic moment when he wrote the bit about a "not negative" function. I wouldn't expect anyone to know what I meant if I wrote "$f$ is negative" or negated that and wrote "$f$ is not negative". If you want to be clear, be explicit and say "$f$ is nowhere positive" or "$f$ is everywhere negative". Always take style guides with a pinch of salt!

Answer (score 0):

The prefix 'non' is not always used inclusively. For example 'let $x$ be nonzero' definitely does not allow the case that $x$ is $0$, and 'let $x$ be nonnegative' means that $x$ is either positive or $0$.

Comment: I don't understand your point; In both of your examples, the prefix "non" denotes a simple negation: "inclusivity" or (to be more relevant to the question") "necessity" is not meaningful in your examples.